# How to send large message data size (>10 KB) using Push notification to Android

Tags: android, asp.net, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have an android app which request for a particular list of data every 10 secs. The size of the response is greater than 10 kb. But I have a battery drainage issue with this kind of architecture. So I thought it would be wiser to implement Push notification service which would be fired from the server each time an action is triggered.

While conducting a feasibility check, I found that the size for a GCM message is limited to 4KB.

How can I fulfill my requirements by using push notification? or is there any other option which I can look into?

Comment: If your payload is too large for the message, you're going to have to make the client request the data. The push message is then simple used as a 'nudge', to say "hey, there is new data, go and fetch it". I suppose you could try 'compressing' the data to reduce its size, but that'll largely depend on the type of data you're pushing. It could be anything: from minimizing the content by removing all whitespaces to something that resembles the 'compress' algorithm available on Unix systems, or a combination of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please send push notification on device and send any code to identify what will you do in this notification.
2. After getting notification please use web-service(API) to get your response from server.

Comment: I'm already requesting for the list and each time I'll be getting a response from the server. The core functionality which I want to achieve here is to get the list from the server without requesting for it.

Comment: But the purpose of gcm is to wakeup to device. You can not send heavy data inside gcm. So need to follow above process or other because its specify by google. I faced same issue so i followed same process.